# Composing CSS shorthand value Sass

Tags: css, sass

I wonder if there is a way to compose/decompose CSS shorthand with Sass. For example, I have:

```
$standardPadding: 4px 2px 1px 2px;
```

and I want to have:

```
$someSpecificPadding: doSomething($standardPadding, top, 2px);
```

then the final value of `$someSpecificPadding` is `2px 2px 1px 2px`.

Is there existing any `doSomething` in Sass (scss) or Less ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code to achieve your desired result

```
@function do_something($list, $args...) {
  @each $mini-list in $args {
    $value: nth($mini-list, 2);
    $position: nth($mini-list, 1);
    @if $position == top {
      $list: set-nth($list, 1, $value);
    }
    @else if $position == right {
      $list: set-nth($list, 2, $value);
    }
    @else if $position == bottom {
      $list: set-nth($list, 3, $value);
    }
    @else if $position == left {
      $list: set-nth($list, 4, $value);
    }
  }
  @return $list;
}
```

The function can be used to change single or multiple positions in the shorthand value as shown below

```
$standardPadding: 4px 2px 1px 2px;

//change both top and bottom values
$standardPadding: do_something($standardPadding, top 18px, bottom 15px);

h2 {
  border-width: $standardPadding;  //returns 18px 2px 15px 2px
}

h3 {
  //changes only top value
  border-width: do_something($standardPadding, top 12px); //returns 12px 2px 15px 2px
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mixin somewhat like this

```
@mixin padding($top, $left: $top, $bottom: $top,  $right: $left){
    padding-top: $top;
    padding-left: $left;
    padding-bottom: $bottom;
    padding-right: $right;
}
```

Comment: Thank @Deepak Bandi for the hint, but your answer seems not solve my question. I wanted something that can override part of existing shorthand

Comment: Glad it helped you.. :)